# how to copy config-files of a modem, using ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh, modem

I have a problem accessing the administrator password of my modem in web interface to reconfigure it. The telnet has been disabled in my modem and I can only 'log in' using ssh.

- Can I copy the configuration files of my modem using ssh?
- Can someone share me a link or a command, on how to access this admin password?

By the way I am using windows xp and ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

If your modem lets you log in over SSH, it probably runs Linux, but with a limited set of available commands. You can copy a single file with the command `scp mymodem:/path/to/file .` where `mymodem` is the host name of your modem. If you want to copy all the files, you need to be a bit more careful, because you need to exclude some special files from `/dev` and `/proc` and `/sys`.

If your modem has the command `rsync`, then the following will do (`-x` excludes filesystems other than the root filesystem):

```
rsync -ax mymodem:/ --exclude=/dev mymodem-files
```

If your modem has only the most basic set of tools, `scp -r` should still work. Make sure to exclude the problematic toplevel directories.

```
mkdir mymodem-files
cd mymodem-files
dirs=$(ssh mymodem ls / | grep -Evx 'dev|proc|sys')
for d in dirs; do scp -rp mymodem:/$d .; done
```

Where the “admin password” is stored is very dependent on the modem. It may be in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` if it's a unix password, or in a completely different place if it's a password solely for the web interface. If the modem software is doing things right, you won't be able to find what the password was, but you'll be able to change it by modifying a file if you locate where the password is and figure out what kind of [hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) is used.

Comment: Sir thank you, but try your line and i got lost. But Sir I got an alternative using PUTTY in windows here the line

Comment: Sir thank you, but I try your line and i got lost. But Sir I got an alternative using PUTTY in windows. after logging in, here's the command line "shell" cd var" "cat curcfg.xml" after that source page was came up. finding the encypted admin password and decode in base64decoder. now i can logging in to admin.thanks